# Ajax Tab - javascript to check which tab is selected

Tags: javascript, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have an AjaxControlToolKit TabContainer with 2 tabs that I load via a custom control in C#. On switching between tabs, I need to fire an event.

Which javascript event should I check for to determine which tab is selected?

Comment: I have an alert method that should be called. Nothing is called.

Comment: i dont know c#  :-) if it is common element try on change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var ai = $find('tc_id').get_activeTabIndex();
if (ai == "1") {
    setDetail1Sync();
}
else {
    setDetail0Sync();
}
```